# NestJS - Request scoped service in transient logger

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm currently trying to extend my logging class in my NestJS (v7) application with a unique request id. When I try to insert my request scoped service in my transient logger, the logger is always `undefined` if I inject it somewhere.

**winston-logger.class.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Logger } from 'winston';
import { RequestInjector } from './request-injector.class';
import { WinstonAdapter } from './winston.adapter';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.TRANSIENT })
export class WinstonLogger {
    private readonly logger: Logger;
    private requestId = 'default';
    private context = 'default';

    constructor(private readonly winstonAdapter: WinstonAdapter, private readonly requestInjector: RequestInjector) {
        this.logger = this.winstonAdapter.getLogger();
        this.requestId = this.requestInjector.getRequestId();
    }

    log(level: string, message: string, ...meta: any[]): void {
        meta.push({ requestId: this.requestId });
        this.logger.log(level, message, ...meta);
    }
    setContext(context: string) {
       this.context = context;
    }
}
```

**request-injector.class.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class RequestInjector {
    private requestId = 'default';

    constructor() {}

    setRequestId(requestId: string) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    getRequestId(){
        return this.requestId;
    }
}
```

If I change the `RequestInjector` to `DEFAULT` (Singleton) or to `TRANSIENT` the logger is defined but if I change it to `REQUEST` the logger is `undefined` if I inject it somewhere. Am I missing something, why this doesn't work?

I can't change the scope of my logger because the context in my logger is `TRANSIENT`.

What I'm trying to achieve is that every class that injects my logger has its own context but should have the same requestId for a request.

Comment: Did you get something out of this ?